# how to setstorageclass for the latest gcloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, lifecycle, gsutil

we use to follow instruction [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles#enable)! to set the bucket lifecycle policy, but with the latest gcloud components update, we are getting an error like this:
Failure: Unsupported tag SetStorageClass.
search the gcs storage lifecycle doc did not fund any update. 
The command we used is `gsutil lifecycle set <json file> gs://<bucket name>/`
and `gsutil version: 4.25`

```
{
   "lifecycle":{
      "rule":[
         {
            "action":{
               "type":"SetStorageClass",
               "storageClass":"NEARLINE"
            },
            "condition":{
               "age":30,
               "matchesStorageClass":[
                  "REGIONAL",
                  "STANDARD",
                  "DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the exact command, inputs, and response that you're getting?

Comment: the rule json is like this:
<code>
{
   "lifecycle":{
      "rule":[
         {
            "action":{
               "type":"SetStorageClass",
               "storageClass":"NEARLINE"
            },
            "condition":{
               "age":30,
               "matchesStorageClass":[
                  "REGIONAL",
                  "STANDARD",
                  "DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
<code>
the command we used is like this one:
`gsutil lifecycle set <json file> gs://<bucket name>/`

Comment: The API does not permit converting REGIONAL to an inherently multi-regional class like NEARLINE; I receive this error when trying to apply the lifecycle JSON you supplied: "BadRequestException: 400 The combination of locationConstraint and storageClass you provided is not supported for your project"

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT 2**

This was fixed in [this GitHub commit](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/commit/481952e7535c2d3bc0c181080e0d77b4e0a2d584), which has been included in the newest version (v4.26) of gsutil.

**EDIT**

It looks like you actually uncovered a bug that occurs when using the XML API. I've opened a GitHub issue an will work on fixing this ASAP:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/427

Thanks for the report!

---

Looking at the code in the Boto library, you're probably trying to specify `SetStorageClass` a JSON key:

```
{
  ...
  "SetStorageClass": ...
  ...
}
```

rather than making it the value of the `action`'s `type` attribute. Here's an example using your (fixed) sample from a question comment:

```
{
  "lifecycle": {
    "rule": [
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "SetStorageClass",
          "storageClass": "NEARLINE"
        },
        "condition": {
          "age":30,
          "matchesStorageClass": ["STANDARD", "DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggesion, I tried with the suggested changes, now getting a different error:
Failure: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with gsutil v4.25.  If you're using an older version, you may want to try upgrading.

Comment: Also, if you're using the XML API, could you try using the JSON API and seeing if it works? This can be done via "gsutil -o 'GSUtil:prefer_api=json' <rest-of-command>".

Comment: I updated to gsutil 4.25, and getting this error: `Failure: Unsupported tag SetStorageClass.`

Comment: I edited my answer above to include the bug you're seeing when using the XML API. Until it's fixed, you should be able to use the JSON API instead.